# How to log arrays with ChromePhp Logger

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, logging, chromephp

Hi all I have the ChromePhp logging extension set up with PhpConsole and it's working fine.

But the usual `ChromePhp::log("Variable value: ".$variable)` doesn't like having $variable as an array. It throws an array to string conversion error.

Is there an in-built method to log the array in human readable format, just like javascript's `console.log(array)`. Or is it a case of iterating over the array and passing each index and value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah easy sorry I got it. I just need to split it into two logs.

```
ChromePhp::log("Array contents: ");
ChromePhp::log($array);
```

This prints to the console as expected in human readable format.

You cant concatenate an array onto a string in the logger.

Comment: Arghh, I was performing silly loops to extract array info because I forgot this very same thing...

Comment: `ChromePhp::log("Array contents: ", $array);` should also work